# External measure invariant under unitary transformations

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, measure-theory

Let us define the *external measure* of the set $A\subset  \mathbb{R}^n$ as $$\mu^{\ast}(A):=\inf_{A\subset \bigcup_k P_k}\sum_k m(P_k)$$where the infimum is extended to all the possible covers of $A$ by finite or countable families of $n$-paralleliped $P_k=\prod_{i=1}^n I_i$, where $I_i=[a_{i,k},b_{i,k}]$ or $I_i=(a_{i,k},b_{i,k})$ or $I_i=(a_{i,k},b_{i,k}]$ or $I_i=[a_{i,k},b_{i,k})$, with $a_{i,k}\le b_{i,k}$, whose measure is defined as $$m(P_k):=\prod_{i=1}^n(b_{i,k}-a_{i,k}).$$
I am intuitively inclined to believe that, if $T\in\text{End}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ is a unitary transformation, then $$\mu^{\ast}(A)=\mu^{\ast}(T(A))$$but I have no idea how we can prove it. Is that so and, if it is, how can it be proved? I $\infty$-ly thank any answerer!

Answer (score 2):

**Note** regarding context: The notation $m$ below refers to Lebesgue measure in $\Bbb R^d$; I'm assuming here that that's already been defined, and we know a few of its basic properties, mainly just that it's finite on bounded measurable sets, is inner regular and satisfies $m(rE)=r^dm(E)$. Now I'm *using* Lebesgue measure in proving that $\mu^*$, and hence $m$, are rotation-invariant. If you feel that's circular it's not. Note however that means that what's below is nonsense if we have not yet proved anything about Lebesgue measure. (If we have not yet defined Lebesgue measure I can't imagine why we're trying to show $\mu^*$ is rotation-invariant first...)

Say two sets are *almost disjoint* if their intersection has measure zero. Say $A$ is *almost the union* of the family $B_j$ if the symmetric difference of $A$ and $\bigcup_jB_j$ has measure zero.

Any open ball is the union of an almost-disjoint family of para..., let's call them rectangles instead, easier to spell. (Draw a picture of a disk; tile it by squares...)

Any rectangle is almost the union of an almost disjoint family of balls. (Draw square $S$. Draw a few disjoint disks $B_1,\dots,B_n$ inside. If you take a huge number of very small disks in $S\setminus\bigcup B_j$ you cover a subset of $S\setminus\bigcup B_j$ of measure at least $m(S\setminus\bigcup B_j)/2$. Repeat.)

So your outer measure is equal to the outer measure defined by coverings by balls, and it's clear that *that* is orthogonally invariant.

---

**Details added  by request:** For $n\in\Bbb Z$ let $D_n$ be the collection of all intervals of the form $$[j2^{-n},(j+1)2^{-n})$$for some $j\in\Bbb Z$. Let $$D=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z}D_n.$$Then $D$ is the set of *dyadic intervals*. One magic thing is that if $I_1$ and $I_2$ are dyadic intervals then either $I_1\subset I_2$, $I_2\subset I_1$, or $I_1\cap I_2=\emptyset$. A *dyadic cube* in $\Bbb R^d$ is a set of the form $$I_1\times\dots\times I_d,$$where each $I_j$ lies in $D_n$ for some $n$ (the same $n$ for every $j$). The dyadic cubes in $\Bbb R^d$ have the property that any two are either disjoint or comparable.

**Lemma 1.** If $V\subset\Bbb R^d$ is a bounded open set then $V$ is the union of a disjoint collection of dyadic cubes.
**Proof:** Let $S$ be the collection of all dyadic cubes contained in $V$. Then the cubes in $S$ cover $V$. Hence the cubes in $M$ cover $V$, where $M$ is the collection of all *maximal* elements of $S$. But the elements of $M$ are pairwise disjoint (because if two of them intersect then one is contained in the other, hence one is not maximal). QED.

If $B=B(x,r)$ is a ball let $3B=B(x,3r)$.

**Wiener's Covering Lemma(WCL 0)** If $F$ is a finite collection of balls in $\Bbb R^d$ then there exists $F'\subset F$ such that the balls in $F'$ are disjoint and $$\bigcup_{B\in F}B\subset\bigcup_{B\in F'}3B.$$

**Proof** This is called the "finite version" of Vitali's covering lemma 
[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_covering_lemma#Statement_of_the_lemma). QED

**WCL 1** If $V\subset\Bbb R^d$ is a bounded open set there exist finitely many disjoint balls $B_1,\dots,B_n\subset V$ with $$\sum_{j=1}^n m(B_j)\ge\frac123^{-d}m(V).$$

**Proof:** Choose $K\subset V$ with $K$ compact and $m(K)>m(V)/2$. Say $F$ is a finite collection of balls with $K\subset\bigcup_{B\in F}B\subset V$. Let $F'$ be as in WCL 0 above. Then $K\subset\bigcup_{B\in F'}3B$, so
$$m(K)\le\sum_{B\in F'}m(3B)=3^d\sum_{B\in F'}m(B).$$QED

**Lemma 2** If $V\subset\Bbb R^d$ is a bounded open set then $V$ is almost the union of a collection of disjoint balls.

**Proof:** Let $B_1,\dots,B_n$ be as in WCL 1 above. Let $V_0=V$, and define $$V_1=V_0\setminus\bigcup_{j=1}^n\overline B_j.$$Note that $$m(V_1)\le\alpha m(V_0),$$where $\alpha=1-3^{-d}/2<1$. Repeat with $V_1$ in place of $V_0$. Etc. Then $m(V_n)\le\alpha^nm(V)\to0$. QED.

Comment: Thank you very much! I see that "Any open ball is the union..." holds because open rectangles are a basis of the topology; I'm not sure how to rigourously verify that "Any rectangle is almost..."... and how do these two things entail what you say in the last paragraph? I heartily thank you!

Comment: @Self-teachingworker Well, not quite. Open rectangles being a basis for the topology says that any ball is a union of rectangles, but it doesn't say a priori that a ball is a disjoint union of rectangles. I'll add some details to my answr.

Comment: Forgive me: once proved these lemmas, how does the fact that my "outer measure is equal to the outer measure defined by coverings by balls" follow? The proofs you give are clear and elegant, but I'm not sure how the existence of the $K$ and $F$ such that $\mu^{\ast}(K)>\mu^{\ast}(V)/2$ and $K\subset \bigcup_{B\in F} B\subset V$ in the proof of WLC1 is guaranteed... Thank you so much again!

Comment: @Self-teachingworker Regarding the second question, do you know what an open set is? Do you know what a compact set is? And are you familiar with the inner regulariity of Lebesgue measure? Regarding the first question, we've shown that if $Q_j$ is a sequence of rectangles and $E\subset\bigcup Q_j$ then there exists a sequence of balls $B_n$ with $E\subset\bigcup B_n$ and $\sum m(Q_j)=\sum m(B_n)$. Also the same in the other direction, from covers by balls to covers by rectangles.

Comment: @Self-teachingworker Oh. I see you asking about $\mu^*(K)$, etc, in your question. I didn't say anything about $\mu^*(K)$. When I write $m$ I'm referring to Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @Self-teachingworker See the Note added at the top...

Comment: I know what open and compact sets are since I've studied some elementary topology, but I don't know what the inner regulariity of Lebesgue measure is since I've only studied Kolmogorov-Fomin's about Lebesgue measure...
As to the proof's conclusion, it isn't clear to me why, if $\{Q_j\}$ is such that $E\subset \bigcup Q_j$, then there is a $\{B_n\}$ such that $\sum m(Q_j)=\sum m(B_n)$ **and** $E\subset \bigcup B_n$: I think you derive it from lemma 2, but I'm not sure how...

Comment: @Self-teachingworker Inner regularity: If $E$ is Lebesgue measurable then $m(E)$ is the sup of $m(K)$ for $K\subset E$ compact. I'm not familiar with Kolmogorov-Fomin but this must be in there.

Comment: @Self-teachingworker About your second question: Is the problem that you don't see at all how it follows from Lemma 2, or is it that you see how it goes but you're concerned about the set of measure zero left over since Lemma 2 just says "is almost the union"?

Comment: As to $m(E)=\sup_{K\subset E} m(K)$, I have posted a [separate question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1804742/lebesgue-measure-as-sup-of-measures-of-contained-compact-sets).
The probem is that I don't see at all how it follows from Lemma 2: are you chosing the balls $B_n$ such that $m((\bigcup Q_j)\triangle(\bigcup B_n))=0$? but how do we see that $E\subset\bigcup B_n$? Thank you so much again!

Comment: @Self-teachingworker I'm still not sure where the problem lies. So I'll say this: My comments was a little sloppy - I should have said that given a cover of $E$ by rectangles $Q_j$ there exists a cover by balls $B_n$ such that $\sum m(B_n)\le\sum m(Q_j)+\epsilon$. (Which is enough to show the two outer measures are the same.) For each $j$ the lemma gives us balls $B_{j,n}$ so $Q_j$ is almost the union of the $B_{j,n}$, and $\sum m(B_{j,n})=m(Q_j)$. So $\sum m(Q_j)=\sum_{j,n}m(B_{j,n})$. And the $B_{j,n}$ _almost_ cover $E$; in fact there is a null set $N$ so that [...]

Comment: @Self-teachingworker $E\subset N\cup\bigcup_{j,n}B_{j,n}$. Now by definition you can cover $N$ by rectangles of total measure less than $\epsilon$, hence by balls of total measure less than $c\epsilon$. Take _all_ the balls I've mentioned and arrange them in a single sequence.

Comment: An important thing: are the $B_n$ open and disjoint, am I right? but not necessarily such that $E\subset \bigcup B_n$, am I right?
If there is a biunivocal correspondence between sequences of (disjoint) $Q_j$ and of (disjoint) $B_n$ such that $\sum m(Q_j)=\sum m(B_n)$ then I understand that the two sets whose infimum is taken are equal and therefore the infimum is the same; but the presence of that $\epsilon$ is cause of my ununderstanding: do you get the desired equality by using some inequality involving the two sums with an $\epsilon$ added?

Comment: @Self-teachingworker The original $B_{n,j}$ are open and disjoint but do not quite  cover $E$; there's that null set $N$ left over. After we add the balls covering $N$ we have a sequence of balls that covers $E$, but they're not disjoint.

Comment: @Self-teachingworker Suppose for every $a\in A$ and $\epsilon>0$ there exists $b\in B$ with $a<b+\epsilon$. Then $\inf A\le \inf B$. Proof: For evvery $a\in A$ we have $a\le\inf B+\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$, hence $a\le\inf B$.

Comment: @Self-teachingworker Wasn't thinking, sorry - the lemma was both wrong and irrelevant. Try this: If for every $a\in A$ and $\epsilon>0$ there exists $b\in B$ with $b<a+\epsilon$ then $\inf B \le \inf A$. Proof: For every $a\in A$ and $\epsilon>0$ we have $\inf B < a + \epsilon$. Hence $\inf B < \inf A + \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$, hence $\inf B\le\inf A$.

Comment: @Self-teachingworker The main thread of the argument has nothing to do with that notion of almost cover. We've shown that if the $B_n$ cover $E$ then there exist $Q_j$ that cover $E$ with $\sum m(Q_j)=\sum m(B_n)$. We've also shown that if $Q_j$ cover $E$ then there exist $B_n$ that cover $E$ with $\sum m(B_n)<\sum m(Q_j)+\epsilon$. Hence the inf for covers by rectangles equals the inf for covers by ballls.

Comment: Forgive me: in the above comment, what do you mean by "$B_n$ ***cover***"? $B_n$ are disjoint open balls, but I'm not sure what the outer measure defined by coverings by balls you introduce in the answer (which we want to prove to be equal to the measure $\mu^{\ast}$ defined by the rectangles) precisely is. I think it's something like $\inf_{E * \bigcup B_n}\sum m(B_n)$ where $*$ is some relation (such that $E * \bigcup B_n$ is the definition of "$B_n$ cover $E$"), but I don't clearly grasp what relation it is... Could you formally write its definition? I heartily thank you!

Comment: @Self-teachingworker When I say the $B_n$ cover $E$ I mean $E\subset\bigcup B_n$. No, the $B_n$ are not disjoint. I explained that the $B_n$ are not disjoint three messages ago. When I said "hencce the inf for covers by rectangles equals the inf for covers by balls" I meant the inf of $\sum m(Q_j)$ over all covers by rectangels equals the inf of $\sum m(B_n)$ over all covers by balls.

Comment: I think I've understood now... For any $\{B_n\}$ (open balls) such that $E\subset \bigcup B_n$ there is a $\{Q_j\}$ (rectangles, in particular dyadic cubes) such that $E\subset \bigcup Q_j$ and $\sum m(Q_j)=\sum m(B_n)$; therefore (from the lemma proved by you in these comments, which I think to be essential to understand all the reasoning) $\inf_{E\subset \bigcup Q_j}\sum m(Q_j)\le \inf_{E\subset \bigcup B_n} \sum m(B_n)$.

Comment: For any $\{Q_j\}$ (rectangles) such that $E\subset \bigcup Q_j$, $\forall \epsilon'>0$, there is a $\{B_n\}$ such that $E\subset \bigcup B_n$ and $\sum m(Q_j)=\sum m(B_n)+\epsilon'$, whence I think we derive (not so trivially, but I think I've been able to prove it to myself) that for any $\{Q_j\}$ and $\epsilon>0$ there's a $\{B_n\}$ such that $E\subset \bigcup B_n$ and $\sum m(B_n)<\sum m(Q_j)+\epsilon$; therefore $\inf_{E\subset \bigcup B_n} \sum m(B_n)\le \inf_{E\subset \bigcup Q_j}\sum m(Q_j)$. Is that the reasoning behind the conclusion? I heartily thank you!

Comment: One thing more: a doubt has arisen in me about the disjoint or comparable nature of dyadic cubes... What does comparable mean? I think that it meant that one must contained in the other one, but, if $d=2$, $[0,2)\times[0,1)$ and $[0,1)\times[0,2)$ are dyadic cubes, but they aren't disjoint and their intersection is $[0,1)^2$.

Comment: No, $[0,1)\times[0,2)$ is not a dyadic cube. Read the definition. As long as I'm typing, your summary two messages back of how we got from balls to cubes was more or less right, but one message back, regarding how we get from rectangles to balls, is full of stuff I don't know where it came from. What _is_ the story on that? I don't see any point to explaining it one _more_ time.

Comment: I understand: dyadic cubes must have equal length of the intervals. As to how we get from rectangles to balls, could you explicitly write the reasoning as I did, as an ehaustive book proof would do, for "balls to rectangles"? I heartily thank you again!

Comment: I could but I'm not going to. I have nothing to say on the matter that I haven't already said at least twice. It's happened many times that I say A, you reply oh, you think I meant B, and I reply that actually no when I said A I meant A. This started as an intersting question - I'm not going to devote the rest of my life to repeating details.

Comment: I apologise for overlooking "the same $n$ for every $j$)" in the definition of dyadic cubes, that was my fault, but it isn't clear to me how things like $\sum m(B_n)<\sum m(Q_j)+\epsilon$ [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1802310/external-measure-invariant-under-unitary-transformations#comment3692994_1802330) are derived and then used to get the desired result, so I have to make suppositions, often wrong, to fill the gaps... Thank you for what you explained to me until now, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

See

https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/measure_theory/measure_notes_ch2.pdf

and check if theorem 2.31. (given with proof) on page 21 solves your problem