# Extending a property of a measure from a bounded set to a unbounded one.

Tags: measure-theory

I was reading this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1804742/lebesgue-measure-as-sup-of-measures-of-contained-compact-sets), but only is proved for bounded sets, and the people who answer say that this should since we have a measure then it all that we need. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that $\mu(A)=\sup \{\mu (K): K \subset A,K \, \text {compact}\}$ it is enough to consider bounded $A$. This is because $\mu(A)=\sup_i \mu (A\cap B_i)$ where $B_i=\{x \in \mathbb R^{n}: \|x\| \leq i\}$. Once you know the result for the bounded sets $A\cap B_i$ you get the result for $A$ since any compact subset of $A\cap B_i$ is also a compact subset of $A$.